# Sqlalchemy group_by

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Currently I need use this query:

```
SELECT name FROM persons WHERE persons."valid"=TRUE GROUP BY "name" ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 10;
```

I need to add **group_by** to my Sqlalchemy:

```
   persons = Model.Person.query.with_entities(Model.Person.name).filter(
                    Model.Person.valid.is_(True)).order_by(
                    asc(Model.Person.name)).limit(settings.items_per_page).all()
```

I need to add group_by as my results contains repeated options:

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Akshay"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Akshay Navle"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alexa"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alexa"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alexa"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alexa"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alexa"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alexa"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Americans"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Americans"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
persons = Model.Person.query.with_entities(Model.Person.name).filter(
                    Model.Person.valid.is_(True)).order_by(
                    asc(Model.Person.name)).limit(settings.items_per_page).group_by(Model.Person.name).all()
```

But get null results, any suggestion?

Comment: change `asc(Model.Person.name)` to `Model.Person.name.asc()`

Comment: if you reduce your query to the `group_by` (so without the `filter` and `order_by`) do you get results?

Comment: Thank you, looks like group_by should be first. This worked: Model.Person.query.with_entities(Model.Person.name).group_by(Model.Person.name).filter(
                    Model.Person.valid.is_(True)).order_by(Model.Person.name.asc()).limit(settings.items_per_page).all()